# Passing a database query to export to PDF in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to ask about export database value to PDF in Laravel.
Sorry I want to inform that im still newbie and have a lot things to learn.
Also, Im not so good in English language, but I hope you all could understand what i wrote here.
Im currently working my own small project, by learning many things on the internet, but now I have some problem with the export data that I select to PDF.
Actually the button works fine. The export to PDF success, but it dont take the variable or data that I want to. Or I could say it just export the template.

Heres my code for the PDF export.

```
public function export_pdf(Request $request,$id){
        $data = ModelDataBG::findOrFail($id);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('formpdf', compact('data'));
        return $pdf->stream('result.pdf');
```

}

And heres code to show the data for export to PDF,

```
@foreach($data as $customer)
$customer['id']
```

What I need to change so the export could take the actual data? and not just the template.
That code actually not mine, I took it from internet. Any help would be very much appreciate. Thank you all.

Comment: Is your view name 'formpdf'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of stream use download :

```
public function export_pdf(Request $request,$id){
            $data = ModelDataBG::findOrFail($id);
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('formpdf', compact('data'));
            return $pdf->download('result.pdf'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Line return one object (not array or collection):

`$data = ModelDataBG::findOrFail($id);`

and you shouldn't use it with **foreach**

So in your template you can print your data like:

`{{$data->id}}`

and for example for print title

`{{$data->title}}`

Comment: oh well, thank you so much. I missed the part that I dont need that foreach.